# Can you simulate a keypress with its key value and not its name?

Tags: python, keyboard, key-value, pyautogui

I want to write a python program, which crashes my computer with the hotkey *Ctrl right* + *Scroll lock* + *Scroll lock*. The hotkey already words but the key value for Scroll lock is 17 and when  *control right* get pressed at the same time, it becomes 3 and in [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), there is no key with the value 3.

Is there a way to simulate a key press with its value and not its name?

```
import pyautogui as pg

pg.keyDown('ctrlright')
pg.keyDown('scrolllock')
pg.keyUp('scrolllock')
pg.keyDown('scrolllock')
pg.keyUp('scrolllock')
pg.keyUp('ctrlright')
```

or

```
pg.hotkey('ctrlright', 'scrolllock', 'scrolllock')
```

Both examples press the right buttons in the right order but when the program presses *Scroll lock*, it presses *Scroll lock* with the key value 17 and not 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the module [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/#description)
that have the same purpose and might help you if it doesn't work with *pyautogui*

https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.send

```
pip install keyboard
```

Here is an example of code :

```
import keyboard

keyboard.press_and_release('shift+s, space')
keyboard.write('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+a', print, args=('triggered', 'hotkey'))
keyboard.press(hotkey)
```